# replace text using c# -Too many characters in character literal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to change text I have using c# , in my mvc edit 
I have use the following code but i'm getting error

> "Too many characters..".

this is the code i'm using :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "AboutId,AboutHeader,AboutText,PicAlt,Url")] About about)
{
    about.AboutText = about.AboutText.Replace('{font-family: "Guttman Calligraphic"; font-size: 12pt; mso-ascii-font-family: David; mso-fareast-font-family: MingLiU-ExtB; mso-hansi-font-family: David;}, "")');

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
```

thanks

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong, if you take the time to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using incorrect override of `Replace` you need to use this:

```
about.AboutText = about.AboutText.Replace("{font-family: \"Guttman Calligraphic\"; font-size: 12pt; mso-ascii-font-family: David; mso-fareast-font-family: MingLiU-ExtB; mso-hansi-font-family: David;}","");
```